# Where is the record of Email --send now (50 or less)

Tags: email

I have been sending email queries to volunteers in the "contacts in the group" area by checking their names and using the " Email send now (50 or less) action.  These emails do not show up in email reports.  Can I pull up the record/history of these emails in any way?  For example I want to send a new message to the same list.  Thanks, probably a beginner question.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "quick email" function (aka "send now to 50 or less") bypasses CiviMail - so they won't show up on CiviMail reports.  If you need CiviMail functionality (e.g. reply/click-through tracking, reporting, reuse, scheduled emails, etc.) you must use CiviMail.

However, you can still pull up a record of these emails, either via Advanced Search or Activity Report.

#### Advanced Search

- **Search menu » Advanced Search**.
- In the "Activities" section, specify "Email" as the Activity Type, and some way of identifying the email in question - perhaps the subject line (see screenshot), or the date.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to track Bounces etc as you would for CiviMail, you can use the [Transaction Email](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional) extension Fuzion created to help fill in this blindspot